# create java code from wsdl file using axis2 wrapper classes

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to generate java source code from a wsdl file using Axis-2, and there are objects that I am expecting to be of the type Long (wrapper class) but they are being generated as long (primitive data type), anyone has an idea on how to generate the java code and keep the wrapper classes as they are without being changed to primitive data types?

Comment: How exactly are you generating your code?

Comment: I am using axis2 code generator in eclipse... I solved my problem by manually changing the type of the fields that I was expecting to be different in the generated code, and it worked... but my question is, is there a problem with using wrapper classes with wsdl? like wsdl doesn't support it or something like that? or is the problem in axis2?

Answer (score 0):

wsdl2java to java generation tool in Axis2 has an undocumented parameter -**Euwc** which can be used for generating the wrapper types.

uwc = USE_WRAPPER_CLASSES

example:`sh wsdl2java.sh -b -o ./out  -S src -d adb -uri ./wsdl/file1.wsdl -wv 1.1 -ss -Euwc -sd -ssi -or -uw -p com.matt.generated`

*These wrapper classes will be generated only when elements are optional ( i.e.: nillable="true" or minOccurs="0"/maxOccurs="1")*

---

For more details regarding the same, refer to the below links:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3353
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4942
- http://yingweiwang.blogspot.com/2012/07/wrapper-types-in-axis2.html